# How can I get better at go-to-goal situations against opposing backline (defense) in FIFA?

Tags: fifa-14, fifa-15

Whenever I play FIFA, there will inevitably come a point where I pass the ball up to my forwards. Suppose I hit the throughball button and my guy is chasing after the pass. I *always* get muscled off the ball and nothing happens with that chance.

How can I actually beat/get past the defender so I have a clear breakaway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use L2/LT to attempt to out-muscle the defender. When you get the ball use left stick to move the ball so that your player is between it and the defender. Use fake shot to work some space by tricking the defender.

However, if you are getting out-muscled it sounds like the problem is that the through ball isn't into space, rather than your striker can't control it. Use L1 to send other players on decoy runs to create space, use the one-two, or play the through-ball into space and time it better, so that the defender is caught out of position.

In other words, as well as perfecting the art of jostling, try also to make more space for your striker to receive the ball in, or have your striker hold the ball up and play it to an advancing midfielder.

Comment: That could be. I had the sense that providing more space might be more the problem too. I watch my bro and he gets muscled too but doesn't have this problem and still gets breaks. Maybe spacing is the issue. Does that mean I should play it more wide when I am sending the through ball? Obviously going in the center makes no sense because the middle is usually packed...

Comment: Well it could mean that you play it out wide, or you play some one touch passing to move the central players out of position, or play it wide to draw a defender out, then play it back into the middle where the space has opened up, or use the decoy run to make the opponent think you are going to play it wide, and then play it into space in the centre. Any option other than playing it to a marked player and hoping he can hold onto the ball.